# jCarousel start autoscroll on mouseover

Tags: javascript, drupal, jcarousel, autoscroll

So as you know jCarousel has an Auto-Scroll feature, good.

I'm not very familiar with js so my understanding of the code isn't that great.

I would like to do the opposite of what they have now I would like for it to start autoscrolling when I mouse over it, instead of stopping it which is what it does now.

Any help is appreciated :)

Or even: I changed it so it switches images when mouseover the arrow(instead of clicking arrow).

Is it possible to have it keep scrolling on mouseover? At the moment when you mouse over it only scrolls once and then you have to mouseover again. Can it be done so it keeps scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, all you should have to do is switch the calls on lines 35 and 37 of the source on [this page](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_auto.html).

```
// Pause autoscrolling if the user moves with the cursor over the clip.
    carousel.clip.hover(function() {
        carousel.stopAuto();
    }, function() {
        carousel.startAuto();
    });
};
```

Just swap "carousel.stopAuto();" with "carousel.startAuto();".  Or, of course, just use those calls in your own code!

Comment: Would it be possible to just make it so when I mouseover the arrow it keeps on scrolling? At the moment I only have it so when you mouseover the arrow it will scroll once and then stop.

Instead of what I originally wanted which was the reverse autoscroll

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.  Try inserting this code into your initCallback function:

carousel.buttonPrev.hover(function()  {
       console.log("Mouse in; starting scrolling");
          carousel.startAuto(1);
    }, function()    {
       console.log("Mouse out; stopped scrolling");
          carousel.startAuto(0);
    });
    
    carousel.buttonNext.hover(function() {
        console.log("Starting scrolling");
          carousel.startAuto(1);
    },
    function()    {
       console.log("Mouse out; stopped scrolling");
          carousel.startAuto(0);
    });

Comment: Here's my version, without the images and other fanfare:  http://pastie.org/8182687  Edits begin on line 51.  Does that do it for you? :)

Comment: Ah. the problem with this is that it will always scroll in the same direction. I need it to go both ways :(